# Call webservice using Retrofit return invalid webservice result

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit

I am using retrofit to retrieve login JSON result from server for that i need to post user name and password. I have tried this code but i get response saying invalid Web Service. but i get correct response using Rest.

My code is something like this,

**MainActivity.java**

```
         String url = "http://***.***.in/***/******/*********/UserService.php?request=Verify_User_Credential";

         //making object of RestAdapter
           RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(url).build();

         //Creating Rest Services
                        RestInterface restInterface = adapter.create(RestInterface.class);

           //Calling method to get login report
                        restInterface.getLoginReport(username, password, new Callback<Model>()

                        {

                         @Override
                            public void success(final Model model, Response response) {


                                if (RetailConnectUtils.isSuccess(model.getStatus())) {
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                           //     retrieve status and message from model and display
                                        }
                                    });
                                } 
                        });


        RestInterface::


           @FormUrlEncoded
           @POST("/GetData")
           void getLoginReport(@Field("username")String  uname,@Field("password")String  password,Callback<Model> cb);
```

and POJO class model containing json converted values It contain method getStatus and getMessage...

Here what should i mention in   @POST("******").. is that webservice method or default retrofit method?